# Custom System Configuration not showing in Store View

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Hi I'm trying to figure out why is it that my custom menu under store->settings->configuration is not displaying when I select the store view. If it's in the Default config its displaying properly but when I select a store view it disappear. May I know why? and how can I have this custom menu display in the system configuration even if I change the store view. Below is my system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="menu_config" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>Menu Config</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mega_menu" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Mega Menu</label>
            <tab>menu_config</tab>
            <resource>My_CustomMenu::mega_menu_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Configuration Settings</label>
                <comment>Setup configuration and behavior of the Mega Menu.</comment>
                <field id="dropdown_custom" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Menu display type</label>                    <source_model>My\CustomMenu\Model\Config\Custom</source_model>
                </field>                        
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

This file is located in my module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is  **showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0"**, you need to change that.

Add following code:

```
<group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it... Can't accept yet need to wait for few minutes